# Text Only Input EditText android

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, restriction

I want to restric user from entering any special character or number into edit text, but programmatically it should allow.

I know I can make `inputType="text"` but it deals only with the softkeyboard. I think it can be achived with TextWatcher, but I am not able to gel evrything. Can anyone help ?

Comment: what you mean by: "programmatically it should allow"?

Answer (score 1):

```
editTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

There are many other types of inputs available for Password, Email address etc. Please see [This API Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Thanks :)

Comment: Thankx but thats the default behavior, I want to make it character only. No numbers or special characters. Character which range A-Z. I achived it with TextWatcher. Thanx anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter input text by following ,

```
etTwamboxName.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start, int end,
                    Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {

                Log.e("", "===> " + src);
                if (src.equals("")) { // for backspace
                    return src;
                }

                if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+.")) {
                    return src;
                }

                return "";
            }
        } });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478388/only-text-in-edittext-on-android/31651138#31651138)

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
android:inputType="text"
```

For more info, you may check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits