# Only Text in EditText on Android?

Tags: android

I want to only text (input) in edittext in App Android.! 
example: Only type "Text: A-> Z", Not allow number or special character.?

Please give me idea, how should it be done?
Thank very much.!

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20868656/1708390)

Answer (score 7):

Try this way,

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
android:inputType="text"
```

For more info, you may check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by the following attribute in ur xml file.

android:inputType

for more on this see this link:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

i think you should set it like this:

android:inputType="text"

or try this:

http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/how-to-create-edittext-allow-only-alphabets-capital-and-smal-t12236.html

Comment: thank, but when i use androi:inputType = "text" 
It also allow input number. :(

Comment: Woa, i find a way do it.!

We can use setOnKeyListener. In this method, we can custom input edittext.!

Thank every body. ^^